# short hend if_else not working with assignment operater

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, shorthand

When i try short hend if_else stetment with assingment operater syntaxerror is happening.i want to result based on the condition.like if condition is true so print 1 otherwise 0.

```
a=100
b=20
c=1 if(a>b) else c=0
print(c)
```

expecting  1 or 0 based on the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
a=100
b=20
c=1 if(a>b) else 0
print(c)
```

you do not have to redeclare that c = 0 after the else, if i am correct.

Comment: This code is working but  c = 0 is not redeclare this is the assignment operator.